# Undelete permission

Tags: apex, trigger, undelete

I have a trigger that doesn't allow me to undelete a record from Recicle Bin in a certain case.

At the same time I also checks security in order to be sure that my user is allowed to Undelete a record, based on the isUndeletable feature of the object: [DescribeSObject-isUndeletable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeSObjectResult_isUndeletable)

But the time I want to test it. How can I check the isUndeletable feature? Looking at Profiles and Permission Sets we are only allow to check the CRUD but nothing related to Undelete.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, if a user deletes a record, they can recover it from the Recycle Bin.  [Per the Help documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=home_delete.htm), recovery of a user's deleted records requires only Read permission on the Object.

So, for your use case, if the running user was the owner of the record being deleted, they simply need Read permission on that SObject type to invoke the trigger in context `Trigger.isUndelete`. No additional checking is required