# How to give Undelete permission to a particular user having a profile in which many other users are also present?

Tags: administration, admin

How to give Un-delete permission to a particular user having a profile in which many other users are also present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, if a user deletes a record, they can recover it from the Recycle Bin.  [Per the Help documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=home_delete.htm), recovery of a user's deleted records requires only Read permission on the Object.

You can create a permission set to assign read permission on given object to that particular user.

Reference: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/106239/20721